# Node Wrangler does not load images

Tags: materials, pbr

I'm working with Blender's built-in Node Wrangler for the first time. Unfortunately, contrary to the tutorial videos, I can't get Node Wrangler to do anything. No errors, just nothing happens when load the PBR files. I configured Node Wrangler to recognize "NormalGL", but still nothing happens when I load the files. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! Blender 3.0, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: You need to have an active node in the shader editor so that Node Wrangler knows what node to hook the images too.  Try selecting the Principled Shader and then adding images.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Marty Fouts, thanks for the suggestion. That works!

Comment: FYI here's where to look for information if nothing's happening : https://i.stack.imgur.com/m05U1.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an active node in the shader editor so that Node Wrangler knows what node to hook the images too. Try selecting the Principled Shader and then adding images.

Be sure that you only have one node selected as Node Wrangled can be a bit too enthusiastic when multiple nodes are selected.

Comment: @WilburPost you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps accept my answer.